# How can I incorporate a square root function into this calculator I am trying to make?

Tags: java, calculator

I am currently making a simple calculator, and I want to incorporate the square root function into it, currently my code looks like this, but it does not work:

```
if ("√x".equals(operator))
{
double sqrt = Math.sqrt(num1);
}
```

Here Num 1 is the input number, but I am not able to find or come up with code that would √x.

Comment: `Math.sqrt` is Javas square root function.  So long as `num1` is a double `Math.sqrt` should work https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)

Comment: can you please tell us how you get the character √. I think you should use the Unicode of √ to do the comparison. If you execute your program from terminal, you have to try to print this character. If you get ? so it will not work. You can use JOptionPane to display it

Comment: So the problem is with the if condition or the calculation?

Answer (score 3):

I think `Math.sqrt(num1);` should work quite good. I suppose you later use the variable 'sqrt', are you sure you are returning it whenever it's needed?